# ActiveAdmin form validation before save

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have form fields from one model `status_history` that I am including in my `member` edit. I am wanting to make it so that if the fields for status_history are empty, then it will not save. Currently it is saving blank items to `status_history` when I save a `members` edit.

My `member` form looks like this

```
form(:html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
    columns do
      column do
        ...
      end
      column do
        f.inputs "Status" do
          f.semantic_fields_for :status_histories, StatusHistory.new do |sh|
            sh.inputs :class => "" do
              sh.input :status, as: :select, collection: {Active: "active", Inactive: "inactive", Separated: "separated"}
              sh.input :date, :as => :datepicker
              sh.input :reason
            end
          end
          table_for member.status_histories do
            column "status" do |status_histories|
              status_histories.status
            end
            column "date" do |status_histories|
              status_histories.date
            end
            column "reason" do |status_histories|
              status_histories.reason
            end
          end
        end

...
      end
    end
    f.actions
  end
```

models/status_histories

```
class StatusHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member

  STATUS_TYPES = [ "active", "inactive", "separated" ]
  validates :status, inclusion: STATUS_TYPES
  validates :date, :presence => true
  validates :reason, :presence => true
end
```

Even adding a button that would toggle the semantic_fields_for would work but currently if I leave them blank I get `validates` errors.

How would I override the save method to check if status and date are present and if so save the `status_history` and if not, do not save the `status_history` but save the rest of the `member` fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

in `Member` ActiveRecord model

`accept_nested_attributes_for :status_histories, reject_if: :all_blank`

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for

Comment: This works perfect. I am able to leave my validates there and they will not be triggered if all are blank.